# Authorization required to install jzos batch launcher

Tags: java, batch, host, authorization, zos

We are trying to install the JZOS Batch Launcher. The function consists of three pieces: a load module that must be put into a z/OS PDSE, a sample start proc that can be tailored and put into an appropriate
PROCLIB, and sample JCL that can be tailored and put into an appropriate SAMPLIB.

On submitting the job we are getting return code=0101. Below are the trace details which we are getting in the job:

```
Output from DD:STDENV config shell script:
 waiting for child shell process to complete
  waitChild()
 child shell process exited with exit code 0
  waitChild()
 Child shell process exited without printing environment; //STDENV should not contain 'exit'
  adoptEnvironment()
  run()
  cleanup()
 JZOS batch launcher elapsed time=0 seconds, cpu time=0.040000 seconds
 JZOS batch launcher failed, return code=101
 cleanup()
 ~JzosVM()
 ~JzosVM()
```

After looking this up and reading more,we then tried to run the job with superuser access and the job ran fine. So we need to know what privileges we require without being a superuser which will enable us to run the job successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the load module into the default location of SYS1.SIEALNKE or some other location? If some other location, my guess is the issue is because the load module is not running APF-authorized. Usually there is a very limited number of people in an installation that can add modules to APF-authorized libraries.

Comment: I have put the load module in the default location SYS1.SIEALNKE.

Comment: Then my next guess would be that the environment for UID 0 is different in some way that makes it work.